# Npm amqplib rabbitmq ackall() vs ack()

Tags: rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I am new with rabbitmq.
I understand that I need to ack messages in order to remove the consumed messages from the queue.
My question is should I use ack() or ackall()?
From the documentation it looks like ackall is dismissing all messeges from the queue,  even messages that are not consumed yet. Is that correct?